# Why does ListObjects return the prefix as a separate object in the array?

Tags: amazon-s3

I uploaded 4 objects to S3. The object keys are as follows:

```
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/MumDad70s.jpg
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/NathanI-1.jpg
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/ProfilePic.png
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/nathan-orange.jpg
```

My code to request the objects is:

```
var req = new ListObjectsRequest()
    .WithBucketName(BucketName)
    .WithPrefix(jobid + "/")
    .WithDelimiter("/");
var objs = _s3Client.ListObjects(req);
```

In the response, even though the prefix is not actually its own object, but rather just a string prepended to the key of the *actual* objects, I get the following *5* objects returned:

```
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/MumDad70s.jpg
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/NathanI-1.jpg
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/ProfilePic.png
4eec12eb0a588620cccad16f/nathan-orange.jpg
```

Why is the prefix being returned as though it were a unique object? How do I *just* return the files with the specified prefix without having to post-filter the list to get rid of the prefix object?

Comment: Not an answer, but a solution - you can detect these such objects by just checking to see if the getSize() on the ListObjects is >0. I would love to know the real answer to this, though...

Comment: Still looking for a good work around for this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per here (and yes, I realize you're probably not asking for the Java documentation): http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest%29

It states:

> If calling listObjects with a prefix value of "foo/" and a delimiter
>   value of "/" on this bucket, an ObjectListing is returned that
>   contains one key ("foo/boo") **and one entry in the common prefixes list
>   ("foo/bar/")**. To see deeper into the virtual hierarchy, make another
>   call to listObjects setting the prefix parameter to any interesting
>   common prefix to list the individual keys under that prefix.

Emphasis mine. It looks like this is actually the intended functionality - to return the prefix common to all the keys.

Comment: Ah, good find. I guess the trick is to just ignore entries ending in /

Comment: It looks like based on the documentation, this will only happen if the delimiter is set - is that correct?

Comment: @AndreiKrotkov that's how I understand it too.

Comment: @AASoft Does not matter if delimiter is supplied or not.

Comment: It's great if Amazon changed the logic recently (I don't know if they did), but there was certainly a difference between having and not having a path delimiter ~5 years ago when this answer was written.